# Specifying the length of a token by the value of another token in ANTLR c#

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr, lexer

I'm trying to create a parsing grammar for bencode based on ANTLR. The syntax has 4 types:

- Dictionary: `d<String><any_other_types>e`
- List:`l<any_other_types>e`
- Number:`i<int_value>e`
- String:`<positive_int>:<sequence_of_any_characters_of_a_given_length>`

Strings are the most problematic because the length of the data after the colon is given by the number before it.

So my question: is there a way to limit the length of a token by the value of the previous token?

My current grammar is:

```
grammar TorrentGrammar;

fileData: 
    line* EOF
;

line: 
    dictionary | list | intData | strData
;

dictionary: 
    'd' keyValue+ 'e'
;

keyValue: 
    key value
;

key: strData;

value: 
    line
;

list: 'l' line* 'e';

strData: 
    NUMBER 
    ':'
    /** StopIndex is readonly */
    {CurrentToken.StopIndex=CurrentToken.StartIndex+System.Convert.ToInt32($NUMBER);}
;

intData: 'i' NUMBER 'e';

NUMBER: ('-')?[0-9]+;
```

The grammar doesn't compile because StopIndex is read-only, so I need another solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set `StopIndex`. Using some [lexical mode magic](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexical-modes), some target C# code and [a predicate](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md) you can consume the appropriate amount of string characters.

A quick demo:

#### BencodingLexer.g4

```
lexer grammar BencodingLexer;

@members {
  private int stringLength = 0;
  
  private void SetStringLength() => this.stringLength = int.Parse(this.Text[..^1]);

  private bool ConsumeStringChars() => (--this.stringLength) > -1;
}

INT_START
 : 'i'
 ;

INTEGER
 : '-'? [0-9]+
 ;

STRING_START
 : [0-9]+ ':' {SetStringLength();} -> skip, pushMode(StringMode)
 ;

LIST_START
 : 'l'
 ;

DICT_START
 : 'd'
 ;

END
 : 'e'
 ;

OTHER
 : .
 ;

mode StringMode;

 STRING : ( {ConsumeStringChars()}? . )+ -> popMode;
```

#### BencodingParser.g4

```
parser grammar BencodingParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=BencodingLexer;
}

file
 : values EOF
 ;

values
 : value*
 ;

value
 : integer
 | STRING
 | list
 | dict
 ;

integer
 : INT_START INTEGER END
 ;

list
 : LIST_START values END
 ;

dict
 : DICT_START key_value* END
 ;

key_value
 : STRING value
 ;
```

After generating the lexer- and parser classes, test it using the following code:

```cs
const string input = "i-42e3:abcl4:spam4:eggsed3:cow3:moo4:spam4:eggse";

var inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(input);
var lexer = new BencodingLexer(inputStream);
var tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
tokenStream.Fill();

Console.WriteLine("\nTokens:");

foreach (var token in tokenStream.GetTokens())
{
  Console.WriteLine($"  {BencodingLexer.DefaultVocabulary.GetSymbolicName(token.Type), -15} '{token.Text}'");
}

inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(input);
lexer = new BencodingLexer(inputStream);
var parser = new BencodingParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
var root = parser.file();

Console.WriteLine($"\nParse tree:\n  {root.ToStringTree(parser)}");
```

which will print:

```
Tokens:
  INT_START       'i'
  INTEGER         '-42'
  END             'e'
  STRING          'abc'
  LIST_START      'l'
  STRING          'spam'
  STRING          'eggs'
  END             'e'
  DICT_START      'd'
  STRING          'cow'
  STRING          'moo'
  STRING          'spam'
  STRING          'eggs'
  END             'e'
  EOF             '<EOF>'

Parse tree:
  (file 
    (values 
      (value 
        (integer i -42 e)) 
      (value abc) 
      (value 
        (list l 
          (values 
            (value spam) 
            (value eggs)) e)) 
      (value 
        (dict d 
          (key_value cow (value moo)) 
          (key_value spam (value eggs)) e))) <EOF>)
```

(I added some indentation to the `ToStringTree` string)